# Setting base tag of iframe C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I set the base tag of an iframe from code-behind, knowing that the iframe's content is set by srcdoc `Attributes['srcdoc']`, My code:

```cs
string baseUrl = ""
string content = Model.RequestDocumentContent(out baseUrl);
Content.Attributes["srcdoc"] = content;
```

```html
<iframe id="Content" name="Content" src="" runat="server" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The content contains images that I need to set the base of them to host URL in order to view them.

Is there any way that I can do that in code-behind?

Comment: you want to set something like `<base href="http://www.example.com/">` in the document of the `Content` IFrame, is that right?

Comment: yes, but i couldn't find a way to add or alter header attributes of iframe from code behind. @Homungus

Comment: `Content.Attributes.Add("src", "https://www.google.nl");`

Comment: One way would be to insert the tag in the `content`, e.g. searching for the head tag there and insert it like a normal string - but thats no easy way because you would need to know a lot about the `content` or else do a lot of parsing. 
Another way is to do it via javascript rendering from server.

Comment: @VDWWD tried that, not wokring :/

Comment: @Homungus i'm trying to avoid that

Comment: there is no other way, because the base-tag is to be inserted in the head section of the new document - so if you are not in control over the returned content of the `Model.RequestDocumentContent`-method, its gonna be the javascript.